# ERROR: Cannot create an AuthInfo instance that will overwrite existing auth data

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

**Background**

I get this error message:

> ERROR:  Cannot create an AuthInfo instance that will overwrite existing auth data.

In the VSCode output panel, when I try and run a unit test:

```
Starting Run Apex test(s)

22:07:35.724 sfdx force:apex:test:run --tests SalesforceReportApiTests.getMatrixReport_success --resultformat human --outputdir c:\projects\sfdx\xxx\.sfdx\tools\testresults\apex --loglevel error
```

I've tried re-authorising using this command:

```
SFDX: Authorize an Org

22:12:42.841 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias xxx --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

But it made no difference.

Running other commands like `sfdx force:source:deploy` work fine

**Questions**

1. What is causing it?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: I am getting this error as well. Just started about 10 minutes ago. Tried creating a new scratch org as well but even though it created it and pushed, I still got the same error trying to assign a permission set to my user. Also tried updating SFDX (was on the latest version) and there are no updates to VS Code or Salesforce Extensions available.

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved itself after ~12 hours.

I assume there was an issue with the Salesforce platform which has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your Salesforce CLI Version, kindly update your Salesforce CLI with latest version.
Command - `sfdx update`
Once updated, retry the Authorization using `sfdx force:auth:web:login`